# MongoDB native HttpClient

Tags: json, mongodb, rest, httpclient, http-request

I'm looking for a way to obtain a HTTP-respone from my REST-service that returns me a JSON object, evaluate it and save it inside my Mongo's stored procedure.

Does anybody know how to do this? I've noticed that MongoDB has a native HttpClient but it seems it's not visible from Server-side Javasript.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with this javascript? Are you trying to do the whole thing of getting everything including the data? I should note that MongoDB DOES NOT HAVE STORED PROCEDURES and it HAS NO SENSE OF THE SUCH. Server-side evaluated JavaScript functions are a completely different matter and you should avoid using them outside of MapReduce really.

Comment: Maybe 'stored procured' is not the best term. I mean JS-function that can be stored and executed vis shell. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/server-side-javascript/

Comment: Sammaye, conceptually, you are absolutely right but still I can't see why the following code is wrong from MongoDB prospective: for (i; i< urls.count(); i++) db.coll.insert({urls[i] : eval(http.get('http://endpoint'))});

Comment: If it is run only from the shell and not evaled via client code then it isn't bad. However talking of the question, I am unsure if MongoDB currently has a method of getting URI resources from other places. Its HttpClient is actually the rst interface which is slightly different from the JS